# addition and subtration uitextfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am trying to do simple addition and subtraction in a `UITextField`. To this end I have two `UIButton`s, one for addition and one for subtraction. The button for subtraction does what it is supposed to do, however the button for addition also carries out subtraction even though I have specified that it adds 0.1 to the value in the text filed. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

```
- (IBAction)decrementIncrementTemperatureValue:(UIButton *)sender
{
   NSString *temperatureString = _temperatureValueInput.text;
   float operator = [temperatureString floatValue];
   float result;

   if (_temperatureDecrement)
   {
       result = (operator - 0.1);
   }
   if (_temperatureIncrement)
   {
       result = (operator + 0.1);
   }
   _temperatureValueInput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
}
```

Comment: what is _temperatureDecrement ND _temperatureIncrement?

Comment: Where are u setting the BOOL value for _temperatureDecrement & _temperatureIncrement.. can u plz provide some more info...

Comment: you can use tag property and check sender.tag

Comment: _temperatureDecrement & _temperatureIncrement are the UIButtons.

Comment: BTW, `operator` should be called `operand`. The operator is either the "symbol" plus or minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

otherwise you can use tag property,and use else if block in the place of multiple if statements

```
decrmentBtn.tag =0;
incrementBtn.tag =1;
- (IBAction)decrementIncrementTemperatureValue:(UIButton *)sender {
NSString *temperatureString = _temperatureValueInput.text;
float operator = [temperatureString floatValue];
float result;

if (sender.tag==0) {
    result = (operator - 0.1);
}
else if (sender.tag==1) {
    result = (operator + 0.1);
}
_temperatureValueInput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are `_temperatureDecrement` and `_temperatureIncrement` instance variables for the two buttons?

If so you want to check if they match `sender`, right now you just check if they are not nil.

```
if (sender == _temperatureDecrement) {
    result = (operator - 0.1);
}
else if (sender == _temperatureIncrement) {
    result = (operator + 0.1);
}
else {
    // if you forgot to wire your two button variables to the UIButton objects
    NSLog(@"sender (%@) is neither decrement nor increment button", sender);
}
```